# How do we pass the string as an application argument? (Algorand, JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, algorand

I'm using the Algorand JS SDK and do not know how to pass string as an application args. I tried multiple methods but did not get any positive result.

Answer (score 0):

You can see examples there:
https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-started/dapps/pyteal/#deploy-and-communicate-with-the-smart-contract

See in particular, this code which passes the string `"setup"` as an application argument.

```py
    setupTxn = transaction.ApplicationCallTxn(
        sender=funder.getAddress(),
        index=appID,
        on_complete=transaction.OnComplete.NoOpOC,
        app_args=[b"setup"],
        foreign_assets=[nftID],
        sp=suggestedParams,
    )
```

One important point is that the string must be encoded into bytes, hence the `b` at the beginning of `b"setup"`.
If the string is a Python `string` object, you need to use the `.encode()` method.
See https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#converting-to-bytes for details.

Note also that nowadays, it is strongly recommended to create ABI-compatible smart contracts.
In that, case the best way to call a smart contract is to use the Atomic Transaction Composer: https://developer.algorand.org/docs/get-details/atc/ rather than directly creating an `ApplicationCallTxn` object.

The same comment regarding the conversion of string to bytes still applies however.

Comment: Hi Fabrice, thanks for your time and support. Actually I knew how to do it in python I want to do it in Javascript. Well I found the answer, Here is how we can pass string as an application argument:

const enc = new TextEncoder();
const note = enc.encode("setupSale");